# Trying to get value of Ng Module values in Ionic 4/ Angular for editable text

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to get some editable text working in Ion-input. So when the user taps on the ion-input, the user will be able to edit the text.

How do I let the Ng model of the `editUserName` & `editUserName` equal to the value of the `UserName` & `UserBio`

I have tried to set the  `editUserName` & `editUserName` it's values on `ngOnInit`

like so

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.recordRow.EdituserName = this.userName;
```

or

```
     this.item.EdituserBio = this.item.userBio;
```

or

```
      this.item.EdituserBio = this.userBio;

}
```

or by simply using the `{{item.userBio }}` in the HTML.

like this

```
  <ion-item>
         <ion-label><strong>Name</strong></ion-label>
         <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.EdituserName" 
        readonly ="false"> 
                {{item.userName}} 
       </ion-input>
      </ion-item>
```

but neither of these have worked for me

HTML

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="userName"> . 
         </ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="User Bio" [(ngModel)]="userBio"> 
        </ion-input>
      </ion-item>



  <!-- this updates the user name -->
      <ion-item>
         <ion-label><strong>Name</strong></ion-label>
         <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.EdituserName"> . 
         </ion-input>
      </ion-item>
        <!-- this updates the user Bio -->
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label><strong>About me</strong></ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.EdituserBio" > . 
      </ion-input>
      </ion-item>
       <div style ="text-align: center">
      <ion-button (click)="UpdateRecord(item)">
          Save Changes 
        </ion-button>
      </div>
```

TS

```
         CreateRecord() {
 let record = {};
 record['profileImage'] = this.profileImage ;
 record['userName'] = this.userName || "";
 record['userBio'] = this.userBio || "";
 this.profileService.create_NewUser(record).then(resp => {   
 console.log(resp);
})
 .catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})

    }

   UpdateRecord(recordRow) {
    let record = {};
    record['userName'] = recordRow.EdituserName || "" ;
    record['profileImage'] = this.profileImage || ""; 
    record['userBio'] = recordRow.EdituserBio || "" ;
    this.profileService.update_User(recordRow.id, record);

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is to use an ion-label to show de value (currently you are using an ion-input just to show the name & bio and another to edit) and then two ion-input to edit:

So this will be your .html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label placeholder="Username"> {{userName}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label placeholder="User Bio"> {{userBio}} </ion-label>
</ion-item>

<!-- this updates the user name -->
<ion-item>
    <ion-label><strong>Name</strong></ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userName"> .
    </ion-input>
</ion-item>
<!-- this updates the user Bio -->
<ion-item>
    <ion-label><strong>About me</strong></ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userBio"> .
    </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try set the default value in constructor

`construct(){
    this.recordRow.EdituserName = this.userName;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. 
just needed to change item.EdituserBio to item.userBio

like

```
     <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.userBio" > .
```